# Python logging; Unable to create log files

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to create a `logFile.log` using:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='logFile.log', filemode = 'a', level=logging.ERROR, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
```

However, I'm running into an OS-Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/Documents/python projects/BOSAPI/demo1/demo1.py", line 28, in <module>
logging.basicConfig(filename='logFile.log', filemode = 'a', level=logging.ERROR, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1976, in basicConfig
h = FileHandler(filename, mode)
File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1143, in __init__
StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
File "/Users/jaypuzhakkara/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1172, in _open
return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/logFile.log'
```

If I explicitly provide a path to *filename=*, the error goes away, but I'd like to have the logFile.log created in the same dir where the script is placed. How do I achieve this?

Comment: try with `./logfile.log`

Comment: Unfortunately, {./logFile.log} didn't work. @SadraNaddaf

Comment: what is your OS? can you create any file in the same directory. I did now how any problem with the exact config you provided

Comment: if you have write access it is probably related to the way you are calling your script, probably you are in another folder and calling the script, where you don't have write access there.

Comment: That's exactly it (see my answer below). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :) @SadraNaddaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling my script from Excel via `xlwings` and I found that the working dir is actually `/` (despite the fact that both script and .xlsm are placed elsewhere).
So I just had to retrieve the path of the script and then provide it in `logging.basicConfig`:

````
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
logging.basicConfig(filename=script_path +'/logFile.log', filemode = 'a', level=logging.ERROR, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')```
````